# Salesforce Navigation Menu - remove home

Tags: salesforce, lightning

[image]

I am very new to saleforce and playing around to get to know how things work.
How do i remove that home button there and can i move that cases and products menu items to right side?

Can you please help check

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a CSS hack to hide the Home icon and option

Click on the Pen icon in the builder and then the CSS button next to the word Branding at the top.

```
.navigationMenuNode:first-child { 
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Matt, I tried this, but when we change styles here, its not aligning fine in Mobile and Ipad

Comment: I only tested in my browser, most likely it's a different CSS class for Mobile, but the concept is the same, if you can determine the class name.

Comment: Thanks Matt, I will try!

Answer (score 0):

GO to builder > Theme > Top Right corner > Edit CSS

[Here it is source image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ysQY.png)

```css
.forceCommunityGlobalNavigation .slds-list__item a, .forceCommunityGlobalNavigation .slds-list__item button {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Please make use of the text formatting options available.

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version of Salesforce/Experience Builder the following can be used to hide just the home tab or the entire navigation menu which is what I needed.

Home tab

```
.themeNavContainer:first-child {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: none;
}
```

Entire nav menu

```
nav { 
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I've used and did the trick:

```
.forceCommunityThemeNav .mainNavItem:first-child {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: none;
}
```